# How Web Service should inform about supported features

Tags: web-services, microservices, versioning, documentation-generation

Different services version could support different features.
For example version 1 of service not support feature x, but version 2 support feature x.

Is there are some standard or practical way to inform which features are supported in current service version?

I think to some way that information could be obtained from commit descriptions. Is there some standard to obtain that information? Or should every service inform about it in own way.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should every service inform about it in own way.

**Don't do this.** This will couple your service with others. Others shouldn't know how to handle your version, but you should know how to handle different versions.

If you use REST and synchronous communication between microservices, you have to look at [REST API Versioning](https://restfulapi.net/versioning/) or [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-versioning). This type of versioning allows you to have multiple versions running in the same infrastructure. Then, each microservice should know how to call a specific version of a microservice.

If you have asynchronous communication with an Event Bus, then your Emitter should send backward-compatible events, to not break other microservices.